# Cluster description not yet available, why?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, maven, insomnia

Hi i'm trying to run my spring boot application connected with mongo, it starts and connects to the database but as soon as I make a request from insomnia it throws these errors:

```
2023-05-24T10:46:37.023+02:00  INFO 21568 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-05-24T10:46:37.024+02:00  INFO 21568 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-05-24T10:46:37.025+02:00  INFO 21568 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
2023-05-24T10:46:37.207+02:00  INFO 21568 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
2023-05-24T10:47:07.222+02:00 ERROR 21568 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=192.168.3.80:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information}}]] with root cause

com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=192.168.3.80:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information}}]
```

These are my config:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {

    @Value("${mongo.host}")
    private String connectionString;

    @Value("${mongo.db}")
    private String db;

    @Value("${mongo.collection}")
    private String collection;

    @Bean
    public MongoCollection<Document> collection() {
        MongoClient mongoClient = create(connectionString);
        return mongoClient.getDatabase(db).getCollection(collection);
    }
```

properties:

```
mongo:
  host: ${DB_URL:mongodb://"myIpAddress":27017}
  username:
  pass:
  db: db
  collection: musica
server.port: 8080
server:
  error:
    include-message: always
    include-binding-errors: always
    include-stacktrace: never
    include-exception: false
```

I tried changing drivers version, checked my firewall, added auto configuration and nothing worked.
Fun fact: my app works perfectly fine when is up on a Docker Container.
Thx!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, it was because of my address ip on the connection string, idk why but changing it with local host made everything work!

```
mongo:
  host: ${DB_URL:mongodb://localhost:27017}
  username:
  pass:
  db: db
  collection: musica
server.port: 8080
server:
  error:
    include-message: always
    include-binding-errors: always
    include-stacktrace: never
    include-exception: false
```